# Getting data from python in Javascript and AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json

I have some issues retrieving info from python and try to show the data in a html page
I get the date from a python script (data.py)

```
import cx_Oracle
import json

lst_proveedores=[{}]
conn_str = 'user/pass@database'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select id, name from provider')
for row in c:
    record1 = {"id":row[0], "name":row[1]}
    lst_proveedores.append(record1)
json_string = json.dumps(lst_proveedores)
print json_string
conn.close()
```

I try to parse the info with AJAX in a html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_get_json(){
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("GET", "prov1.py", true);
    hr.responseType = "JSON";
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json", true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
                        results.innerHTML = "";
                        for(var obj in data){
                                results.innerHTML += data[obj].id+" is "+data[obj].nombre+"<hr />";
                        }
            }
    }
    hr.send(null);
    results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">ajax_get_json();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but doesn't work
I setup apache to execute python scripts and work with very simple scripts, but doesn't work when I retrieve data from the database
How can I show the data in a html page?
Or what language or framework may I can use to show the data 
Any advice
I am desperate
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try visit your python files in browser. If you can't see json print on page, there're problems in your server or python code.

If it works, that may be something wrong in your Ajax request.

You can use jQuery or zepto.js to help. They contain a method of Ajax: $.ajax.

You can visit: http://zeptojs.com
And search "$.ajax" on the page for help; )

===============================================================

try this:

```
//var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
var data = JSON.parse(hr.response);
```

===============================================================

and this is my onreadystatechange function code, use it if it helps:

```
ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = function(){
    //console.info('[Ajax request process] url:' + url +'; readyState:' + ajaxObject.readyState + '; status:' + ajaxObject.status);
    if (ajaxObject.readyState == 4 && ((ajaxObject.status >= 200 && ajaxObject.status < 300) || ajaxObject.status == 304)){
        var result = null;
        switch (dataType){
            case 'text':
                result = ajaxObject.responseText;
                break;
            case 'xml':
                result = ajaxObject.responseXML;
                break;
            case 'json':
            default:
                result = ajaxObject.response ? JSON.parse(ajaxObject.response) : null;
                break;
        }
        if (typeof(success) == 'function'){
            success(result,url);
        }
    }else if (ajaxObject.readyState > 1 && !((ajaxObject.status >= 200 && ajaxObject.status < 300) || ajaxObject.status == 304)){
        console.warn('[Ajax request fail] url:' + url +'; readyState:' + ajaxObject.readyState + '; status:' + ajaxObject.status);
        if (typeof(error) === 'function' && errorCallbackCount == 0){error(url);errorCallbackCount++;}
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I test the AJAX code and work with a simple json file, but with the python script don't work

Comment: @Joseleg what happen if you visit your python script directly in browser like chrome?